# JavaScript variable definition confusion

Tags: javascript

I have 2 javascript code. Bothe of them check if varable equal to null or type of variable is undefined. But in one condition I get error and in other I don't get any error.

Code 1:

```
if (NS1 === null || typeof (NS1) === 'undefined') {
    ...  }
```

Code 2:

```
 if (window.NS1 === null || typeof (window.NS1) === 'undefined') {
  ...   }
```

For code 1 I get error

> NS1 is not defined

while for code 2 I don't get any error. I don't understand what might be the reason as i have not defined NS1 or window.NS1 . So I should get error in both the condition.

Comment: `NS1 === null` --- you're trying to retrieve a value of the variable that does not exist.

Comment: `typeof` is not function. Use like `typeof window.NS1`

Comment: If you move the `typeof` check to the left-hand-side of the `||`, you won't get any errors at all due to short-circuit evaluation ~ `if (typeof NS1 === 'undefined' || NS1 === null)`

Comment: Note that this is a special case, only global variables can be accessed as properties of some object (the global/window object). Variables within function's can't be accessed as properties, so for them you must use *typeof* if uncertain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So I should get error in both the condition.

Trying to access<sup>1</sup> an *undeclared variable* results in a reference error. However, trying to access a *non-existing property*, like you do in the second example, will simply return `undefined`, not throw an error:

```
> console.log({}.foo);
undefined
```

That's just how JavaScript works.

---

1: One could argue that you are also accessing the variable when you do `typeof NS1`. While that's true, `typeof` is special. It will return `"undefined"` even if the variable is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `null === undefined // --> false`

`NS1 === null` refers to variable *NS1* which is not defined, so it throws exception.

But `window.NS1 === null` will evaluate as *false*, because *window.NS1* is undefined. And undefined is not equal to null

**NS1** as undeclared variable --> exception
**window.NS1** as undeclared property --> undefined